# shapeless breaks sbt incremental compilation

Tags: scala, sbt, shapeless, incremental-build

I have a scala project which I build using sbt 13.5.

Since I implemented a module using shapeless, whenever sbt tries to incrementally compile the project it fails in resolving the required implicits:

> [...] could not find implicit value for parameter mapper [...]
>
> [...] could not find implicit value for parameter folder [...]

and so on.

`sbt clean` and `sbt compile` solves the issue, but the project is fairly big and this is painfully slowing down the compilation times and my productivity in turn, as fresh build can take several minutes.

Any idea of what's going on here?

---

#### some extra info

So, after some more thinking I made some hypothesis. The issue occurs when using shapeless records, and by looking at the generated files, I think it could be an issue with the macro that generates the singleton type for each record key.

My module takes an `HList` of `ColParser[T, K]` declared as:

```
sealed trait ColParser[T, K] {
  val columnL Witness.Aux[K]
}
```

So the compiler generates a `Witness` for each `ColParser` using a macro, and I'm afraid sbt loses track of the generated macros when deciding what to recompile, but this is just a sketchy hypothesis.

As a matter of fact, whenever I change something in the code that invokes my module (e.g. I add/remove a `ColParser` from the `HList`), I get the above error.
Forcing the recompilation of the module (by deleting the generated `.class`) fixes the issue.

Comment: Really impossible to say without seeing the details of the project.